# how to install envoy using pip..?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do make install, but I keep getting an error. I already tried following this answer: Can't install via pip .
 I get the below error:

```
 C:\Python33>pip install envoy
  Downloading/unpacking envoy
 Downloading envoy-0.0.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package envoy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pom\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_pom\envoy\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import envoy
  File ".\envoy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core import *
ImportError: No module named 'core'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

 File "c:\users\pom\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_pom\envoy\setup.py", line 6, in <module>

import envoy

File ".\envoy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

from core import *

ImportError: No module named 'core'

    Cleaning up...
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in  
       c:\users\pom\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_pom\envoy

 Storing complete log in C:\Users\pom\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: envoy isn't quite compatible with Py3 yet. What you can do, though, is download the package from PyPI manually, run 2to3 over the extracted source and then run python3 /extract/path/setup.py install .